# Do events have to propagate up component hierarchy?

Tags: lightning-web-components, event

I have an app with a component that looks like this:

[image]

When the button is clicked, the datatable needs to know, so I've got this code executing when the button is clicked:

```js
this.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('myevent', {
        detail: { key: this.value }
    })
);
console.log('myevent dispatched');
```

My datatable then has this:

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.template.addEventListener('myevent', (event) =>
        console.log('myevent', event)
    );
}
```

Clicking the button shows the first log to the console, but not the second. I thought this kind of event listening is possible, but perhaps the only way to get the event from the button to the datatable is to move up the hierarchy and then back down to the datatable? Can the datatable just directly listen for the event?

Comment: [Configure Event Propagation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_propagation) explains event propagation alongside configuration options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, events can only go up the component hierarchy; this closely follows how the DOM works, with a few extra tweaks (e.g. you can prevent components from going all the way to the root). However, sometimes you want to be able to communicate directly between two components. This is where the [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) comes in. Using this feature, any two components, regardless of their relationship, can communicate with each other directly.

You can also use Window.postMessage to communicate within the same DOM, though this is a little bit trickier to use once you start setting up a bunch of these. LMS uses a subscriber/publisher model to make sure that each component gets only the messages they want, unlike Window.postMessage, which sends events to all registered listeners.

In general, I'd recommend LMS for any situation where a specific component needs to talk to anything other than its direct parent (including grandparents), as that involves potentially leaking events all the way up the hierarchy (glls' link to the documentation explains more about why this is generally a bad idea).

Of course, depending on your design model, you may still choose to reorganize your components such that the container will forward the message to the child if you find that easier, but at least you now know that there are other options.

Comment: Thanks so much. I now remember experimenting with LMS months ago for a different reason. It worked perfectly.